# Computer doesn't beep when starting with only motherboard, power supply, and CPU. Is the motherboard dead?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I recently purchased a motherboard with my graphics card and CPU. After installing everything, it starts up, but there is no output. When I stripped down to just the power supply, motherboard, and CPU, it doesn't beep like there is no RAM, but all the fans and lights come on.

Is this DOA? I just want to be sure.

**MB**: Asrock 990fx extreme3
**Graphics**: amd radeon 7870 ghz oc edition
**CPU**: amd fx 8320 black edition

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no output"?

Comment: When you remove the RAM, does it beep then?

Comment: No it does not beep.

Answer (score 1):

The 8320 CPU is not supported by the ASRock 990FX Extreme3 motherboard. You can find the complete [support list on ASRock's web site](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/990FX%20Extreme3/?cat=CPU).

Comment: Which means, essentially, that it acts like there is no CPU.

Comment: There are many people using this board with the 8320 "Please check the BIOS version lable on the BIOS chip is 1.30 or newer to support FX-8320."  AsRock SUPPORT From http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=13-157-281&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&Pagesize=10&PurchaseMark=&SelectedRating=-1&VideoOnlyMark=False&VendorMark=&IsFeedbackTab=true&Page=12  So it looks like the list might not be updated.  (wouldnt be the first time)

Comment: Looks like I may have overlooked this I did consider it but i forgot before i submitted the RMA well I will see in a weeks time. Thank you I just assumed that the Bios were up to date...